# UITableViewCell label crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, exc-bad-access

[image]I am working on XCode 8.2.1, I am getting this exception and my application crashed in UITableView cell label.

Please suggest me how to fix the issue, also I have enabled zombie tool for an app, getting the crash for some time.

```
 Webthread(19) 1: EXC_BAD_access (code=1 address 0x8)
 Webthread(20) 1: EXC_BAD_access (code=1 address 0x8)
 Webthread(25) 1: EXC_BAD_access (code=1 address 0x8)

 barNameLbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
 barNameLbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 //   barNameLbl.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Bold" size:15.0f+5*isiphone6Plus()];
 barNameLbl.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Bold" size:15.0f];

 barNameLbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;

 // barDistanceLbl=nil;
 barDistanceLbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,30, 200,10)];
```

Comment: You may need to show more code than this.  How do you add the label to the cell, for example? Is this crash happening in a custom UITableViewCell or is it happening in a bar button item (I see the name "`barNameLbl`").  Also, what line of this code does the crash actually happen on?

Comment: Do you have a crash log? Is it `barNameLbl` or `barDistanceLbl` that is causing the issue? Which line exactly causes the crash?

Comment: share some more relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @larme,@KKRocks,@michael

Comment: barDistanceLbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,30, 200,10)];


mostly i am getting crash this line

Comment: I have attached screen shot.

Comment: I think barDistanceLbl is not a UILabel... check in your storyboard

Comment: @Praksh barDistanceLbl is a label i have created programmatically

Comment: Check the code where you created Outlet for `barDistanceLbl`, is it UILabel or someother one....

Comment: How you declare barDistanceLbl ?

Comment: UILabel * barNameLbl;
 UILabel * barDistanceLbl;

@Fares Ben Hamouda I am getting crash this label

Comment: @Vignesh i have created label programatically.

Comment: And do you have a crash log? Is `barDistanceLbl` a property ? strong? weak? Did you write assign instead?

Comment: @Larme No i am not getting any crash log and i dont assign any property.

Comment: @Mss iOS Check the width of UITableView Cell..... Here you had given a width of 200,... Check if TableViewCell width is greater than this

Comment: @VigneshDavins

Here is the my code for tableview cell
 self.barsListTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,CGRectGetMaxY( segmentedControl.frame)+30, SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT+10*isiphone6Plus()-(CGRectGetMaxY(segmentedControl.frame)+segmentedControl.frame.size.height+138))];

Comment: @Mss iOS Post some more code to get a clear idea